# Trying to union these together but I can't figure out what it's telling me: Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: mysql

This is the code that I have going:

```
SELECT e.EncounterID, YEAR(e.EntryDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(e.EntryDate) AS 'Month', ac.Description AS 'PresentingProblem', c.ClinicName 
FROM encounters AS e
JOIN clinics AS c
ON e.clinic = c.ClinicID
JOIN activitycodes AS ac
ON e.PresentingProblem = ac.ActivityCode
UNION 
SELECT ec.Description, dc.Reason AS 'Discharge_Reason', a.Duration, a.ExtraTime, nc.Description AS 'No Show Code'
FROM encountercodes AS ec
JOIN dischargecodes AS dc
ON ec.EncounterCode = dc.DischargeCode
JOIN appointments AS a
ON dc.DischargeCode = a.DischargeCode
JOIN noshowcodes AS nc
ON a.NoShowCode = nc.NoShowCode
```

Comment: "Selected columns listed in corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same data type." - from [13.2.10.3 UNION Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html).

Comment: Each column in the 2 joined queries must be of the same TYPE so if col1 of query1 is an INT then col1 of query2 must also be an INT etc etc

Comment: And you might like to read this before asking your next question https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Sorry, I'll learn how to format properly next time. Thank you all for answering though!

Comment: You undoubtedly have a conversion mismatch in your selected values. Run each individual select by themselves and note the type of each column returned. Then carefully compare the results of the output. Each column must match in type. Sometimes the SQL engine can upcast some types to help with matching so that chars and varchars may comengle.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems.

1. Top select shows EncounterID, does that match with description from the second select? I doubt it.
2. Then you have Year matched up with reason. Also not good.
3. Then Month lined up with duration.
4. etc.

Just match up your types on your SELECT columns.

```
SELECT e.EncounterID, YEAR(e.EntryDate) AS 'Year', MONTH(e.EntryDate) AS 'Month', ac.Description AS 'PresentingProblem', c.ClinicName 

SELECT ec.Description, dc.Reason AS 'Discharge_Reason', a.Duration, a.ExtraTime, nc.Description AS 'No Show Code'
```